# Does the apical bud grow back after being removed?

Tags: botany

My question pertains to the apical bud which asserts apical dominance in plants. After it is removed, apical dominance is lifted, what happens to that part of the shoot after that? Does it stop growing? Can the (previous) apical bud be restored or do other axillary buds take over as the dominant apical tip?